# Redirect user if it's not logged in

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, links

can you help me with little problem.

I need to find a solution, how to redirect user to login page when he wants to download file over link in post content, so, I have some files and I want them to be available only for users that are logged in, otherwise they should be redirected on login page, for example I want to forbid access (download) for all files from wp-content folder, keep in mind that I have several of those folders in the root, I tried with `.htaccess` file file but its not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?brt\.keezst\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov)$ http://brt.keezst.com/ [NC]
```

Comment: Very bad to rely on cookies for this. The user could simply set a cookie with the same name and *any* value, and they'd have access to the files.

Comment: True, its not good practice but it's not that important in this case, they just force user to make profile (not necessary), if i find another solution I will post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Marcelo Henriques](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/44437/marcelo-henriques-cortez) answer i figured out how to make this work with `.htaccess` file and here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*(mp3|m4a|pdf|doc|xlsx|docx|xls)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://website.com/login/
```

place .htaccess file in folder you want to protect from non registered users and it will do the job, last line is redirect.

So, if you want to protect file access over anchor link, from specific folder (uploads/media) make .htaccess file inside folder and paste this code.
If you want just `403`(forbiden) change `RewriteRule (.*) http://website.com/login/`  with `[R=403,L]`

Comment: This doesn't actually check to see if the WP user is _logged in_ (as per your question). This simply checks for the absence of `wordpress_logged_in` anywhere in the `Cookie:` header (which is easily faked). You can't _authenticate_ the WP user in `.htaccess` alone.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use htaccess for that.

What I would do is make a 'download page' template and use it to 'serve' the files.

By doing that, I can do a check with `is_user_logged_in()` [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) and redirect with `wp_login_url()` [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url)

Just do:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) :
//file link
else :
    wp_login_url();
endif;
```

I think it's easier and safer to do that. Besides, you can even make that into a plugin later and use it on another projects or keep using it if you change your site template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, I already have around 30k links on website, it's website that is moved from Joomla cms to wordpress, I could do that but it would be time consuming. I need something like htaccess solutions so i can just place it there and all links from that folder wont be accessible if user is not logged in.

Comment: Ok, got it. So, are your files located in the 'upload' folder?

Comment: Yes, and there are several more folders in root folder that I made that are containing files from old installation, website is huuge so I'ts hard to upload every file into media, it's easier just to move whole directory and change permalinks with MySQL querry.

Comment: If you can move everything to the 'upload' directory its easier to prevent access for non-logged users. You can also check this post: [link](https://www.willmaster.com/blog/contentprotection/htaccess-cookie.php)

Comment: The user will still be able to download the files if they can guess the URL in the `wp-content` path. Depending on your exact situation, this ranges from easy to very easy.

Comment: Not if you use a dinamic link, wich is very easy to make with PHP

Answer (score 1):

I recently wanted the same, except I wanted to secure invoices only.

I put this above the WordPress part of the .htaccess

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*wp-content/uploads/invoices/.*
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(invoices/.*)$ read-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
</ifmodule>
```

This redirect everyone that wants to go to a file in the invoices directory to read-file.php wich is located right in the toplevel of WordPress as well.
read-file.php has the following code to check if the user is logged in

```
<?php
// Load wp
require_once('wp-load.php');

// If user is logged in
if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

    // Redirect to home
    wp_redirect( url to your login page );
    exit;
}

// Additional checks here
// Headers to open or download the file
// readfile( $file );
// exit;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, this could be solution too, but I found solution above, check that, it's more simple.

Comment: Unlike the other solution, this actually prevents access to files in the `wp-content` directory (or relevant subdirectory). You could easily adapt this to block all access to the `wp-content` directory.

Comment: What's not given here is the code to deliver the file if the user *is* logged in. You're redirecting them to the login page if they aren't logged in but if they are logged in then they'll just be left with a blank page. Hint: look at PHP's `readfile` function and make sure to avoid exploits that will give someone access to files on your web server that are outside the `wp-content` directory.

Comment: @MichealJohnson that's right. I should not forget that part. Though in my case its only to open PDF files wich i created the headers for. But i'll still add it to prevent confusion.

Comment: @Wilco That's not good. Someone could write `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/../../wp-config.php` and get your Wordpress config file (including database username and password), and depending on your web server configuration they could also write `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/../../../../../../../etc/passwd` and get your server's passwords (and a bunch of other things).